# Can I redirect a domain with redirecting its subdomain?

Tags: domains, redirects, 301-redirect, subdomain

I would like to redirect domain A to domain B, but I have a subdomain under domain A. If I redirect it, is the subdomain going to be redirected to domain B as well?

Answer (score 3):

No, top-level domains (`example.com`) can be redirected independently with regards to their subdomains (`www.example.com`, `notredirected.example.com`).

The typical setup for what you're describing is to redirect `example.com` and `www.example.com` to Domain B, but keep `notredirected.example.com` serving.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  I get it now.

Comment: @NadezdaKoseva Awesome! Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it thoroughly answered your problem!